# How to open the Drafts folder of Gmail in Android when a list is clicked?

Tags: android, gmail

How do I open of Drafts folder of Gmail? I can open the inbox.

Comment: Please elaborate. Question is vague.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported, as there is no publicly documented and supported API for the Gmail application, which may or may not even exist on any given Android device.